# Hide Ok button on onDateChanged in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, date, datepicker, calendar, datepickerdialog

I want to hide the Ok button when the date is changed. Below is the code that I have written but the buttons do not change:

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "onDateChanged " + "Year: " + year + "\n" +
                                        "Month of Year: " + monthOfYear + "\n" +
                                        "Day of Month: " + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, null, datePickerDialog);
                        datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", datePickerDialog);


                    }});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just comment it `datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, null, datePickerDialog);`

Comment: @MD tried, still the same.

Comment: `*button-name*.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`; doesn't work for you?

Comment: buttons are defaults. not customized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.!

```
datePickerDialog.getButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Pleasure.! didn`t really think it was this simple. took a while though

Answer (score 0):

By hiding the OK button you does not want user to select the date. DatePicker is not your custom dialog that is why may be it would be difficult to hide the button. You can restrict user for click on OK button

```
    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "onDateChanged " + "Year: " + year + "\n" +
                                            "Month of Year: " + monthOfYear + "\n" +
                                            "Day of Month: " + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  datePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                        "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                if ("Your date condition") {
                                 // perform your action
                                }
                            }
                        });
                            datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", datePickerDialog);


                        }});
```

Comment: what I want to do is to hide the button in the first place so that there wont be any action.